# MySQL query stalling - is there a more efficient solution for this MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT post_title, 
       count(*) AS c
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = "product"
GROUP BY post_title
HAVING c > 1
ORDER BY c DESC
```

runs no problem, returns result in < 1 sec.  Yet

```
select * from wp_posts where post_title in (
    select post_title from wp_posts WHERE post_type = "product"
    group by post_title having count(*) > 1
)
```

hangs up.

Yet they are fundamentally the same query except for the fact that in the second query I'm trying to pull out the entire record rather than just the `post_title`.

Have I erred?  Is there a more efficient way to achieve the equivalent?

Edit: `EXPLAIN` query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_posts` has been appended for your information.
[image]

[image]

Comment: does post_title has index on it? your second query does not look optimal. please sahre your table definitions as well as explain plans

Comment: Questions about query performance should include a `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` output for every table involved in the question.. And a `EXPLAIN <query>` output for every query involved in the question.. Otherwise this question is unclear and most likely be to be voteclosed.

Comment: Now provided in original question.

Comment: @Simonare what does index mean?  What MySQL command will output table definitions/explanations?

Answer (score 1):

you could avoid the IN clause  on the subquery and use an inner join

```
select a.* 
from wp_posts a
INNER JOIN (
    select post_title 
    from wp_posts 
    WHERE post_type = "product"
    group by post_title 
    having count(*) > 1
) t ON t.post_title = a.post_title
```

this should be more performant

Comment: MySQL said: 
`#1051 - Unknown table 'siliconharvestdb.a'`

Comment: Would you have the patience to explain the `a.*` as I'm new to MySQL and am not fully following the logic?  Thanks.

Comment: in  SQL you can use alis for table and columns name  ..  in this way you can use write code more clear and compact .. hope is clear

Comment: How does your solution compare to Gordon Linoff's?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to write this query is probably using `exists` . . . assuming `wp_posts` has a primary key:

```
select p.*
from wp_posts p
where p.post_type = 'product' and
      exists (select 1
              from wp_posts p2
              where p2.post_title = p.post_title and
                    p2.post_type = p.post_type and
                    p2.id <> p.id
             );
```

For performance, yu want an index on `wp_posts(post_type, title, id)`.

Comment: MySQL said: `#1054 - Unknown column 'p2.title' in 'where clause'`

Comment: `For performance, yu want an index on wp_posts(post_type, title, id).`  Could you please explain this to a noob?